# Mex function with OS X 10.9.5 and Xcode 6.2?

Tags: xcode, macos, matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I'm using Matlab Coder in Matlab-r2014b in OS X 10.9.5. I have Xcode 6.2. I'm unable to generate a Mex function using Matlab compiler. I'm reporting here a sample code with structure and type of variables similar to my real one.

1) The script that calls the entry-point

```
clear all
N=3 ;              
Res=alg(N);
```

2) The entry-point

```
  function val=alg(N)

  profindex=randi(N+1,2^(N-1),1);
  for s=1:10
  coder.varsize('matrix');
  matrix=zeros(1,3*N+2);
  for k=1:2^(N-1)
      if profindex(k)==N-1
         matrix=[matrix; randi(1,1,3*N+2)];
      end
  end

  if size(matrix,1)>1
      matrix(1,:)=[];
  end

  for k=1:size(matrix,1)
      for h=1:size(matrixfinal,1)
          if sum(matrix(k,2+2*N:3*N)==matrixfinal(h,2+2*N:3*N))==N-1
             matrixfinal(h,3*N+1)=matrixfinal(h,3*N+1)+matrix(k,3*N+1);
             matrixfinal(h,3*N+2)=matrixfinal(h,3*N+2)+matrix(k,3*N+2);
          end        
      end
  end
  end
  if size(matrixfinal,1)>1
      matrixfinal(1,:)=[];
  end
  val=matrixfinal(1,1); 
  end
```

When I try to built the Mex Function I get the following error

> ??? Build error: Compilation returned error status code 2. See the
>   target build log in the report for further details. 
>        Error in ==> alg Line: 1 Column: 1   Code generation failed: Open error report.

If I open error report, It reads

> 1   xcrun  -sdk macosx10.7  clang -c -fno-common -arch x86_64
>   -isysroot  -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -fexceptions -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O2 -DNDEBUG  -I ".... 
>  2   xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located. 
>  3   xcrun: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a
>   developer tool or in PATH 
>  4   gmake: *** [alg_mexutil.o] Error 72

I found [these](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103904-can-i-use-xcode-5-as-my-c-or-c-compiler-in-matlab-8-1-r2013a-or-matlab-8-2-r2013b) instructions but they are for 10.8 and if I replace 10.8 with 10.9.5 it does not work and I get always the same errors and in the following order

> SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located
>
> SDK "macosx10.8" cannot be located
>
> SDK "macosx10.9.5" cannot be located.

How to fix these errors?